# Getting sound but no video on Android app?

Tags: android, cordova, embed, android-sdk-2.3

I've created an Android app which is for a small town to locate recreational activities. Fairly small and basic. I designed it with phonegap.

I've scoured the web for (22 hours) on this problem.

When I embed videos in the app (from anywhere) I get the audio, but no video.

Comment: You need to post code for us to help you.

Comment: It would just be something an android app developer would have encountered or not. Not a code issue.

Comment: embed it in iframe, Ive got vimeo videos working in my app

Comment: Yeah. We've got it in an iframe. It's just something else going on. Tried updating phonegap. A lot of people seem to be having the same problem. No solutions I've seen thus far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with youtube and vimeo embed videos. But everything works in fullscreen mode.

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXXX" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```